# Bootstrap 4 website bug: using a custom data attribute to pass a class from section to navbar does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am working on a website in Bootstrap 4, that has sections with light and dark backgrounds and a fixed navbar.

The navbar is dark (has the css class `bg-dark`) and, while it is easily visible against the light sections, it is indistinguishable *against the dark* ones.

I have found a simple solution to this problem: I use the custom data attribute `data-navbar-classes` with one of the values `navbar-light bg-light` and `navbar-dark bg-dark` to pass the 2 classes from section to navbar, as the section reaches the top of the page.

There is a **bug** in the script and I can not find it:

```js
var toggleNavbarClasses = function() {
  var navbarHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(),
    classChangeTrigger = navbarHeight / 2;
  $('.page-section').each(function() {
    var $pageSection = $(this),
      pageSectionClasses = $pageSection.data('navbar-classes'),
      fromTop = $pageSection.offset().top;
    if (fromTop < classChangeTrigger && fromTop >= 0) {
      $('nav.navbar').removeClass('bg-dark navbar-dark')
        .addClass(pageSectionClasses);
    }
  });
};
$(window).scroll(toggleNavbarClasses);
//toggleNavbarClasses();
```

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}

.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-dark bg-dark" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-light bg-light" class="container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur illum perferendis totam delectus quas earum ea labore, deserunt placeat sit, amet veritatis, saepe itaque! Velit vitae accusantium maiores corrupti cupiditate!</p>
</div>
<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-dark bg-dark" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should find out which section is the `navbar` located and then determine the `class` of it.

But in your code, the only case that satisfied `fromTop < classChangeTrigger && fromTop >= 0` is the first `page-section` since others `fromTop` always greater than `classChangeTrigger`.

In this case, you can simply find out which section is the `navbar` located by calculating `outerHeight` and `offset().top` of the `page-section` and the current `scrollTop` like the following:

```js
var toggleNavbarClasses = function() {
  var navbarHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(),
    classChangeTrigger = navbarHeight / 2;
  $('.page-section').each(function() {
    var $pageSection = $(this),
      pageSectionClasses = $pageSection.data('navbar-classes'),
      fromTop = $pageSection.offset().top;
      height = $pageSection.outerHeight();
      scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if(scrollTop>=fromTop && scrollTop <= (fromTop+height)){
        $('nav.navbar').removeClass('bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-light bg-light').addClass(pageSectionClasses);
      }
  });
};
$(window).scroll(toggleNavbarClasses);
```

```css
.page-section {
  padding: 70px 10px
}

.page-section.bg-dark * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-dark bg-dark" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-light bg-light" class="container-fluid bg-dark page-section">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur illum perferendis totam delectus quas earum ea labore, deserunt placeat sit, amet veritatis, saepe itaque! Velit vitae accusantium maiores corrupti cupiditate!</p>
</div>
<div data-navbar-classes="navbar-dark bg-dark" class="container-fluid bg-light page-section">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```